# How to filter a the required content from a string in linux?

Tags: linux, string

I had a string like:-

```
sometext sometext BASEDIR=/someword/someword/someword/1342.32 sometext sometext.
```

Could someone tell me, how to filter this number 1342.32, from the above string in linux??

Comment: are `sometext`'s always delimited from `BASEDIR=/ssdf/sdf/sdf/1324.12` with a space on each side?

Comment: This is terribly underspecified.  Can 'sometext' contain whitespace or digits?  What distinguishes the number that you want from that which you don't?  What do you want from `BASEDIR=/foo/345/bar/928.3k4/baz/34/blah`?

Answer (score 0):

If sometext is always delimited from the surrounding fields by a white space, try this

```
cat log.txt | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~
/BASEDIR/) {print i,$i}}}' | awk -F/ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~
/^[0-9][0-9]*$/) {print $i}}}'
```

The code snippet above assumes that your data is contained in a file called `log.txt` and organised in records(read this awk-wise)

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes space will be there and sometimes its like /someword/someword/someword/1342.32/sometext/sometext. so is it possible to get the number, like in some cases space will be there and in some cases as i said above some text will be there

Comment: edited. Also, the more I look at the code, the less I like it... I'm sure that if you dive into some essential awk training you can come up with a simpler, more readable code.

Comment: sorry, thats not working , till here:- cat log.txt | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~
/BASEDIR/) {print i,$i}}}', is fine here we are getting, like basedir= sometext/sometext/1345.76/sometext. but after this the last line of command is not returning anything. but here we need to filter the number 1345.76. could you please make changes i n the above command. Its really needed for me. Thanks!!

Comment: I forgot the dot   xD ... This will work pal. `cat log.txt | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~/BASEDIR/) {print i,$i}}}' | awk -F/ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~/^[0-9.]+$/) {print $i}}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "sometext BASEDIR=/someword/1342.32 sometext." |
    sed "s/[^0-9.]//g"
> 1342.32.
```

The sed command **s**earches for anything not in the set "0123456789" or ".", and replaces it with nothing (deletes it). It does this in **g**lobal mode, so it doesn't stop on the first match.

This is enough if you're just trying to read it. If you're trying to feed the number into another command and need a real number, you will need to clean it up:

```
$ ... | cut -f 1-2 -d "."
> 1342.32
```

cut splits the input on the **d**elemiter, then selects **f**ields 1 and 2 (numbered from one). So "1.2.3.4" would return "1.2".

Answer (score 0):

This works also if digits appear in `sometext` before `BASEDIR` as well as if the input has additional lines:

```
sed -n 's,.*BASEDIR=\(/\w*\)*/\([0-9.]*\).*,\2,p'
```

- `-n` do not output lines without `BASEDIR…`
- `\(/\w*\)*` group of `/` and `someword`, repeated
- `\([0-9.]*\)` group of repeated digit or decimal point
- `\2` replacement of everything matched (the entire line) with the 2nd group
- `p` print the result